# is 65 minutes enough to connect in FRA from JFK to Beirut?

Tags: layovers, short-connections, fra

Is 65 minutes enough to connect in FRA with Lufthansa Business class ticket coming from JFK going to Beirut?
It looks like gates yesterday were Z62 arrival from JFK- and B33 to depart to BEY

Comment: If your flights are on a single ticket, the airline thinks you can make it.

Comment: There are several questions on this site about transit times in Frankfurt. Please use search and read the answers.